# My vscode python codes files which is not opening in vscode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, python-3.10

I have many python code files of my course which used to open in vscode, now unfortunately it's not opening in vscode. Please can anyone help me.

Comment: @JavadNikbakht Hello, my question is I have downloaded python code files, which were vscode view only files, it used to open but now it's not opening in vscode for several days. Can you help please

Comment: Can you open them with other text editors like vim, nano or notepad++ etc?

Comment: the answer depends on your OS. I think the association between the py files and VS Code is gone. Google for `ENTER_YOUR_OS_HERE set default file association`

Comment: Please [edit] to provide more details. What is your OS? What version of VS Code are you using? What exactly are the type of files you are opening, .py files? How are you opening the file, by double-clicking or by opening VS Code and then selecting File > Open? What exact error messages do you get or see on VS Code?

Answer (score 0):

Many times, when we use vscode to open files sent by others or modify configuration files, we will find that files cannot be modified.

In fact, it is not that the file cannot be modified, but vscode editing adopts a mode similar to VIM editor. It can be modified only by typing `"i"` (insert). After modification, you cannot save it by typing `"Command + s"` (MacOS) or `"control + s"` (Windows). You need to type `"ESC"` and then `"WQ + enter"` to save.

Comment: Isn't this because you have [VIM for VS Code extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vscodevim.vim)?